# JavaFX LineChart wrong sizing and coordinates

Tags: java, javafx-8, linechart

I'm trying to implement a LineChart (that updates every second). But the sizing is completely wrong: I set the `MaxSize` and `PrefSize` to `94, 31` but when I run it, the actual size is `144, 98`. I tried to make it bigger/smaller and each time it becomes bigger/smaller, but again the wrong size.

Also the positiong is wrong, my X is set to by `64`, but the outcome is `109`.

What am I doing wrong with the chart? The other elements in my pane don't act like that. So it's only the chart that does weird things.

Java:

```
xAxis = new NumberAxis(0,LENGTH,3);
yAxis = new NumberAxis(MINIMUM,MAXIMUM,10);

chart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

chart.setId("Data");

chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
chart.setAnimated(false);
chart.setLegendVisible(false);
chart.setCreateSymbols(false);

chart.autosize();

chart.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
chart.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
chart.setVerticalZeroLineVisible(false);

chart.setAlternativeColumnFillVisible(false);
chart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);

yAxis.setForceZeroInRange(true);

data = new XYChart.Series<Number,Number>();
data.setName("Position");
data.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number,Number>(seconds, prevY));

chart.getData().add(data);

chart.getYAxis().setOpacity(0);
chart.getXAxis().setOpacity(0);

pane.getChildren().add(chart);
```

CSS:

```
#Data {  
    -fx-max-width: 80px;
    -fx-max-height: 20px;    
    -fx-pref-width: 80px;
    -fx-pref-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us code example?

Comment: Probably the min size is larger than the pref size you are requesting. Try setting it as well.